# check if argv is a directory

Tags: function, shell, directory, fish

I'm using FISH (Friendly Interactive SHell)

and I created 2 functions :

```
function send
    command cat $argv | nc -l 55555
end
```

--> send a file via nc

```
function senddir
    command tar cjf copy.tar $argv; cat copy.tar | nc -l 55555; rm copy.tar
end
```

--> send a dir by compressing it via nc

Now, I wan't to refactor and create a send function that does both, for this I need to check if argv is a dir. How can I do it with fish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as in other shells, although in `fish` you are actually using an external program, not a shell built-in.

```
function send
    if test -d $argv
        command tar cjf copy.tar $argv; cat copy.tar | nc -l 55555; rm copy.tar
    else
        command cat $argv | nc -l 55555
    end
end
```

Actually, you don't need the temp file and can pipe the output of `tar` directly to `nc -l`, which allows you to simplify the function to

```
function send
    if test -d $argv
        command tar cj $argv
    else
        command cat $argv
    end | nc -l 55555
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function send
    if test -d $argv
        command tar cjf $argv | nc -l 55555;
    else if test -e $argv
        command cat $argv | nc -l 55555;
    else
        echo "error: file/directory doesn't exist"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `$argv` is an *array*, so if you pass more than one argument, `test` will barf.

```
$ test -d foo bar
test: unexpected argument at index 2: 'bar'
```

Coding a little more defensively:

```
function send
    if test (count $argv) -ne 1
        echo "Usage: send file_or_dir"
        return

    else if test -d $argv[1]
        # ...

    else if test -f $argv[1]
        # ...

    else
        # ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, "argv" means vector of arguments :)